# How to calculate space complexity of function A when A calls function B in for loop?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, space, space-complexity

I am curious about how to calculate space complexity and auxiliary space of function A, when A calls function B in for loop. lets describe two example:

---

**case 1:** What is the space complexity and the auxiliary space of function `A`

```
void A(int k) {
    int c = 25;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        B();
    }
}

void B () {
   int d = 5;
}
```

---

**case 2:** What is the space complexity and the auxiliary space of function `A`

```
void A(int k) {
  int c = 25;
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
     int d = 25;
  }
}
```

---

What is the difference between this two case? (of course if there is a difference)

Comment: `of course if there is a difference` ... actually, both loops appear to me to not build up any state whatsoever.  The loops either declare a local variable, or call a function which declares a local variable, but then that variable just goes out of scope at the end of each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

The loop (as shown) adds nothing to the space complexity.  On each iteration of the loop, the stack frame for `B` is allocated, and then discarded.  `B` doesn't allocate memory internally, so its space consumption is O(1), and so is `A`.

If the code looked like:

```
std::vector<int> B(int i) {
    std::vector<int> result(i);
    // Do something with result;
    return result;
}

void A(int k) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> storage;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        storage.push_back(B(i));
    }
}
```

Then we can see that each invocation of the function `B` allocates O(k) space, and it is called O(k) times, so the space complexity of A is O(k²).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get that, but what about auxiliary space? How can I calculate it for function A? My colleague told me something like that: if you have just for loop ( `n iteration` ) in function, and if you have just one line in it ( `int k = 5;` ) the auxiliary space of function A is O(n), is it right or not ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "auxiliary space", but although I can conceive of a standard compliant C++ compiler which uses different storage for each iteration through the loop, I know of no such compiler.  They all reuse the storage each time through the loop.

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili when `A` has run, O(k) distinct objects of automatic storage duration have existed, but at any point in time, only O(1) are alive. Is that the distinction you are after? And in the modified example, there are additionally O(k²) objects of dynamic storage duration.